# Python: Convert to local time

Tags: python

I have a python `datetime` object in a database, and it is stored in UTC timezone:

`2012-10-24 14:10:00+00:00`

I am able to convert it to local time, using

```
start_localtime = start.replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('Europe/Zurich'))
```

start_localtime is now: `2012-10-24 14:10:00+02:00`

Which is fine, technically. But I need the timezone be `+00:00`, so the hour would be 16 (+2 hours).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: 14:10:00 UTC is 16:10:00+02:00 in Zurich. You wanted it to be 16:10:00+00:00? That's a completely different time altogether.

Comment: I know. But I need to do some calculations with time objects, and they do not have timezones.

Comment: Then why not just call `start_localtime.time()`? It returns `datetime.time(16, 10)` (no timezone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using datetime.astimezone()?

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone

I figured out a way to do it using the pytz library: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> a = datetime.now(timezone("UTC"))
>>> b = a.astimezone(timezone("Europe/Zurich"))
>>> a
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 10, 39, 20, 158993, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> b
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 11, 39, 20, 158993, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Zurich' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
>>> b.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

Comment: Yes. The result is the same: 2012-10-24 14:10:00+02:00

Comment: i updated my solution to include some sample code using the pytz library, hope that helps.